# Como comentar bloco de código em JSX (React)

Tags: react, comentários, react-dom, jsx

Quero saber se é possível comentar um bloco de código dentro do método render() no React, tentei de todas as formas que conheço e nenhuma deles funcionou.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="Events">
        <div className="EventDescription">Multi-Eventos</div>
        <div className="EventHeader">
          <Button onClick={this.addEvent.bind(this)} bsStyle="warning">Adicionar Eventos 
            <FontAwesome name="chevron-down"/>
          </Button>
          // Não funciona
          <!-- Não funciona -->
          /* Não funciona */
          -- Não funciona
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Para comentar em jsx, deves colocar chavetas à volta dos comentários, de resto é como fizeste no teu segundo exemplo (`/* Não funciona */`):

```
{/* COMENTÁRIO JSX */}
```

Answer (score 9):

Podes ler sobre isto na [documentação do React](http://chenglou.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#comments), mas basicamente há 4 tipos diferentes.

Fiz um jsFiddle de exemplo aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/mk50r5qt/

O código é:

```
var Span = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <span style={{color: this.props.color}}>
                {this.props.text}
            </span>
        );
    }
});


var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (<div>
            <Span {...this.props} text={'Hello'} />
            {/* comentário entre componentes */}
            <Span {...this.props} text={' World!'} />
        </div>);
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    // comentário ao estilo JavaScript
    < Hello /* comentário dentro do componente */ name="World" /*
    comentários de multiplas linhas funcionam também!
    */ color={'blue'}
    /> ,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**#1 - comentários entre componentes:**

dentro de JSX, entre componentes a sintaxe é `{/* texto aqui */}`. A razão das chavetas `{}` é para interpretar como JavaScript e aí sabemos como comentar.

**#2 - comentários fora e antes de componentes:**

```
render: function() {
    return ( 
        // comentário antes do componente contentor...
        <div>
```

**#3 - comentários dentro das tags de componente na mesma linha:**

```
<Hello /* comentário dentro do componente */ name="World" />
```

**#4 - comentários dentro das tags de componente em linhas multiplas:**

```
<Hello name="World"
   /*
      comentários de multiplas linhas funcionam também!
   */ 
   color={'blue'}
/>
```

http://chenglou.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#comments